# Joining two tables on historical date

Tags: t-sql, join, sql-server-2012

I have two tables. The first one:

```
col1 | col2 | ColumnOfInterest | DateOfInterest
--------------------------------------------------------
abc  | def  |       ghi        | 2013-02-24 17:48:32.548
.
.
.
```

The second one:

```
ColumnOfInterest | DateChanged             | col3 | col4
--------------------------------------------------------
       ghi       | 2012-08-13 06:28:11.092 |  jkl | mno
       ghi       | 2012-10-16 23:54:07.613 |  pqr | stu
       ghi       | 2013-01-29 14:13:18.502 |  vwx | yz1
       ghi       | 2013-10-01 14:17:32.992 |  234 | 567
.
.
.
```

What I'm trying to do is to make a 1:1 join between the two tables on the ColumnOfInterest and so that the DateOfInterest reflects the date from the second table.

That is, the line from the first table would be joined to the third line of the second table.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: so you are trying to get the max date from the DateChanged column for each distinct ColumnOfInterest?

Comment: Well, not the max date... as you can see the second table is a kind of a history table, so I need a row which was relevant at the DateOfInterest from the first table... Hope it makes sense

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: Well essentially all the columns from both tables, without duplicating those I'm joining on

Comment: The second table is, for example, a list of price changes with their effective dates and you want to find the price that would have been in effect for a particular date in the first table. Or, stated differently, for a given `DateOfInterest` you want the `DateChanged` that either matches or immediately precedes it, right? Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I meant. :) Relevant tag added.

Comment: Oh I understand. Should be simple enough with LEAD()

Answer (score 1):

```
select table1.ColumnOfInterest, max(table2.DateChanged) 
  from table1 
  join table2 
    on table1.ColumnOfInterest = table1.ColumnOfInterest 
   and table1.CDateOfInterest >= table2.DateChanged 
 group by table1.ColumnOfInterest
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  'abc' col1,
        'def' col2, 
        'ghi' ColumnOfInterest,
        CAST('2013-02-24 17:48:32.548' AS DATETIME) DateOfInterest
INTO #DateOfInterest


CREATE TABLE #History 
(
ColumnOfInterest VARCHAR(5), 
DateChanged DATETIME,
col3 VARCHAR(5), 
col4 VARCHAR(5)
)
INSERT INTO #History
VALUES  ('ghi','2012-08-13 06:28:11.092','jkl','mno'),
        ('ghi','2012-10-16 23:54:07.613','pqr','stu'),
        ('ghi','2013-01-29 14:13:18.502','vwx','yz1'),
        ('ghi','2013-10-01 14:17:32.992','234','567');

;WITH CTE_Date_Ranges
AS
(
SELECT  ColumnOfInterest,
        DateChanged,
        LAG(DateChanged,1,GETDATE()) OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnOfInterest ORDER BY DateChanged) AS end_date,
        col3,
        col4
FROM #History
)

SELECT  B.*,
        A.*
FROM CTE_Date_Ranges A
INNER JOIN #DateOfInterest B
ON B.DateOfInterest > A.DateChanged AND B.DateOfInterest < A.end_date
```

Results:

```
col1 col2 ColumnOfInterest DateOfInterest          ColumnOfInterest DateChanged             end_date                col3  col4
---- ---- ---------------- ----------------------- ---------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----- -----
abc  def  ghi              2013-02-24 17:48:32.547 ghi              2012-08-13 06:28:11.093 2015-04-21 18:46:46.967 jkl   mno
```